# Behaviour of | symbol in regex

Tags: java, regex, split

This is my string

```
String s = "asadsdas357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC";
```

I split it as

```
String a[] = s.split(s, i);
```

outputs: i=0

```
        |   |   1   9   0   |   |   R   U   E       R   A   C   H   E   L   L   E   |   |   S   T   |   |   |   L   E   S       C   È   D   R   E   S   |   J   7   T   1   J   9   |   Q   C
```

First two indexes of array are empty nad then each index has one character.

When i=1, output is the whole original string

```
asadsdas357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

when i=2, output is

```
    ||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

first index of array is empty and second contains the substring from first **|** symbol

when i=3, output is

```
        ||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

first two indexes are empty and last index has the same substring as for i=2

when i=4, output is

```
        |   |190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

first two indexes empty, next contains a pipe and last the rest

when i=5, output is

```
        |   |   190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC
```

first two empty, next two pipe character and last the remaining.

as the i value increases, the output is

```
first two indexes empty
next all indexes except last contains one character each
last index contains the remaining string
```

My questions are

1. Why it is not considering the first word before the first pipe symbol?
2. Why it is making he first two indexes empty for every value of i except 1?
3. The pattern is the same string here, so what is matched here and how the outputs come?

And another thing is if I replace the **pipe** symbol with any other symbol such as **@ or ! or %**, the output is

```
array length is 2 with both indexes has empty strings. this is for i>=2
```

for i=0

```
the array length is also 0
```

for i=1

```
the array length is 1 containing the whole string.
```

Is it taking the **pipe** symbol as a special regex symbol?

Any help appreciable.

Comment: `s.split(s, i)` - Why are you using the string to split itself? That's really bizarre.

Comment: Yes, its unusual but to learn regex I just experimented it, but now confused about the behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` method takes a regex as an input param. Now the regex in your case is 
`asadsdas357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC` and the second parameter `i` is the number of times that split operation is applied. This is the explanation of your regex

```
                         // Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "asadsdas357902" +       // Match the characters “asadsdas357902” literally
"|" +                    // Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "|" +                    // Empty alternative effectively truncates the regex at this point because it will always find a zero-width match
                         // Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "190" +                  // Match the characters “190” literally
"|" +                    // Or match regular expression number 4 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "|" +                    // Empty alternative effectively truncates the regex at this point because it will always find a zero-width match
                         // Or match regular expression number 5 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "RUE\\ RACHELLE" +        // Match the characters “RUE RACHELLE” literally
"|" +                    // Or match regular expression number 6 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "|" +                    // Empty alternative effectively truncates the regex at this point because it will always find a zero-width match
                         // Or match regular expression number 7 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "ST" +                   // Match the characters “ST” literally
"|" +                    // Or match regular expression number 8 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "|" +                    // Empty alternative effectively truncates the regex at this point because it will always find a zero-width match
                         // Or match regular expression number 9 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "|" +                    // Empty alternative effectively truncates the regex at this point because it will always find a zero-width match
                         // Or match regular expression number 10 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "LES\\ CÈDRES" +          // Match the characters “LES CÈDRES” literally
"|" +                    // Or match regular expression number 11 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   "J7T1J9" +               // Match the characters “J7T1J9” literally
"|" +                    // Or match regular expression number 12 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   "QC"                     // Match the characters “QC” literally
```

So, your regex is effectively equivalent to `asadsdas357902|` in a way because the regex that comes after it is never tested. See the `split` method documentation here [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

This code would give you the same output

```
private static void splitWithPipe() {
    String s = "asadsdas357902||190||RUE RACHELLE||ST|||LES CÈDRES|J7T1J9|QC";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String a[] = s.split("asadsdas357902|", i); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` is a special character in regular expressions, indeed. It means "Either the stuff to the left of me, or the stuff to the right of me", so `ab|cd` matches either `ab` or `cd`. This can be further constrained by parentheses.

If you want to do a regex split at `|`, then you need the regex `\|`, which in Java needs to be written as `"\\|"` in a string.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions you don't need a double `|` symbol - that will just confuse things. You may wish to consider visiting [a site with regular expression tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and use the web site [regular expression tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: What for do I need a "double `|`" in regex?

Comment: @stema - My mistake - see the edit. Has a phone call half way through typing that post and lost my train of thought